# how to check for existence of multiple patterns in bash

Tags: bash, wildcards, pattern-matching, globstar

i have several patterns that include ** wildcard, let them be:

```
foo/**/bar.xml
foo/**/baz.xml
```

and i have an example dirtree:

```
$ tree foo/
foo/
└── deep
    ├── baz.xml
    └── even
        └── deeper
            └── baz.xml
```

what would be easiest way to check if any of those patterns is fulfilled? to be precise: return nonzero **only if none** is found. what I came up with so far is to use `globstar` and `nullglob`. But `ls` is not an option here, as if no pattern is satisfied, is lists current directory. So i had to utilize `echo`, like this:

```
$ (shopt -s globstar nullglob; echo foo/**/bar.xml foo/**/baz.xml) | grep .
foo/deep/baz.xml foo/deep/even/deeper/baz.xml
$ echo $?
0
```

vs

```
$ (shopt -s globstar nullglob; echo foo/**/bar.xml foo/**/beque.xml) | grep .
$ echo $?
1
```

so yeah - it works. but maybe i missed something and there is **simpler/more elegant** way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

You could use a function:

```
non_empty() (($#))
has() (
  IFS=
  set +o noglob
  shopt -s globstar nullglob extglob
  shopt -u failglob # which has precedence over nullglob!
  for glob do
    non_empty $glob && return
  done
  false
)
```

```
if has 'foo/**/bar.xml' 'foo/**/baz.xml'; then
  echo matches found
fi
```

(or `has 'foo/**/ba[rz].xml'` or (with `extglob`) `has 'foo/**/@(bar|baz).xml'` or `has 'foo/**/bar.xml' || has 'foo/**/baz.xml'`)

It stops at the first glob that has a match.

To make it more efficient and stop at the first match, you could use `zsh` instead and its `Y1` glob qualifier:

```
has() {
  local glob
  for glob do
    ()(($#)) $~glob(NY1) && return
  done
  false
}
```

(also inlining the `non_empty` into an anonymous function).

`**/` for recursive does come from zsh in the early nineties and enabled by default there (copied by bash but not enabled by default in the late 2000s). Alternation is done with `has 'foo/**/(bar|baz).xml'` in `zsh`.

In `zsh`, you can also do:

```
alias has='noglob has'
```

So as to be able to do:

```
if has foo/**/bar.xml foo/**/baz.xml; then
  echo matches found
fi
```

Without having to quote the glob operators.

Answer (score 0):

If it's ok to overwrite the list of positional parameters:

```bash
shopt -s globstar nullglob

set -- foo/**/bar.xml foo/**/baz.xml

if [ "$#" -ne 0 ]; then
    echo matches found
fi
```

This sets the list of positional parameters to the names matching the globbing pattern. Since `nullglob` is in effect, the list will be empty if no matches are found.  The value of `$#` is the length of the list of positional parameters.

Using your idea of running it in a subshell:

```bash
( shopt -s globstar nullglob; set -- foo/**/bar.xml foo/**/baz.xml; [ "$#" -ne 0 ] )
```

---

Using an array in place of the list of positional parameters:

```bash
shopt -s globstar nullglob

names=( foo/**/bar.xml foo/**/baz.xml )

if [ "${#names[@]}" -ne 0 ]; then
    echo matches found
fi
```